# Sending multiple responses to the server

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to send id of the button when the button is clicked. But when I click the button it sends 10 xhttp request to the server, it should send only one. I'm not able to find out the problem.

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script>
function fun1(element) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "/pre?"+element.id, true);
    xhttp.send();
    //alert(element.id);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="fun1(this)" id="img1">IMAGE</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only one request is going in the above code. add you full code

Comment: Hi @sojin this is the complete code and surely on the server side I'm getting 10 request once I clicked the button

Comment: check the browser network, check how many requests are sent from the browser. the issue must be something other. i didn't found any issue with the above code

Comment: @sojin just checked it, only in Firefox it's sending the request 10 times whereas in chrome it sends 1 time only. What could be the reason behind it and How can I rectify it?

Comment: Hi, The problem has been solved, I'm sending the "200" after receiving the response.

Answer (score -1):

The problem has been solved, I'm sending the "200" after receiving the response.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).